# Django-Pycharm problem on Windows " OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found "

Tags: python, django, pycharm, gtk3

Django project where I use PyCharm version 2023.1.1 on Windows.
But when running the command in the terminal

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
```

or

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```

or

```bash
python manage.py runserver
```

Obs: **The files he says he didn't find in the path exist except for one o** 'libcairo.2.dylib'

It shows error with the following message:

> raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover OSError: no library
> called "cairo-2" was found no library called "cairo" was found cannot
> load library 'C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll':
> error 0x7e cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e cannot load
> library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e cannot load library
> 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e

I have already reinstalled GTK3 and already defined the `PATH` in the GTK3 environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

GTK 3 for Windows https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases

https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases/download/2022-01-04/gtk3-runtime-3.24.31-2022-01-04-ts-win64.exe (46.7 MB)

In Windows, add to `PATH` environment variable. Need close all CMD windows, then re-open for environment variable in effect.

Answer (score 0):

In the case I discovered what could possibly be, python was not properly installed and I also needed to have its path in the 'PATH' as an environment variable, after installing python properly and defining its path in the 'PATH' as an environment variable, I also reinstalled env

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).